# Loaded MobileNet model giving wrong predictions

Tags: tensorflow, go, imagenet

I am trying to load ***mobilenet_v2_1.4_224*** (link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet) which was trained in **TensorFlow**, and serve it in **GoLang**.

Thing is when I try to make a prediction of image with a panda, I get the wrong prediction. My guess is I downloaded wrong imagenet label file. On which imagenet dataset was network i mentioned above trained on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK MobileNet from the Tensorflow Model Zoo is trained on ILSVRC-2012-CLS, which has 1,000 classes including Giant Panda and Red Panda.

However as MobileNet is not 100% accurate, you might experience varying results depending on the input image you provide. Make sure to make it is tightly cropped around the Panda, and try various images, as some might return incorrect labels as even the best MobileNets V2 models have an accuracy around 70% on the ImageNet dataset.

If you want to be able to classify pandas more precisely, I'd suggest retrain your MobileNet model with a Panda dataset. There are plenty of available examples on how to do this, I have linked a couple below using the MobileNets architecture and Tensorflow as Framework.

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining

https://hackernoon.com/creating-insanely-fast-image-classifiers-with-mobilenet-in-tensorflow-f030ce0a2991

https://medium.com/@sumit.arora/training-a-neural-network-using-mobilenets-in-tensorflow-for-image-classification-on-android-14f2792f64c1

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

If you haven't tried it before, you might want to look at Google Codelab's Tutorial, it's really easy to follow:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0